# How did Aragorn’s army reach Mordor so easily?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

How did Aragorn’s army reach Mordor so easily, whereas Frodo took 17 months to reach Mordor with so many difficulties?

Comment: they used roads. Frodo did all he could do to stay hidden and walk the paths nobody sane would walk.

Comment: Agree on the main answer. Like Napolean said "never interrupt your enemy when he's making a mistake". The relatively low numbers of Gondorians is compensated for somewhat by the fortifications of Minas Tirith. Not enough to win outright of course, but enough to survive as long as they did and most likely inflict much greater casualties on the attackers than they suffered themselves. But then a mass cavalry charge into the orcs' stationary flank, especially because it was unexpected, would have been devastating. It's not all about numbers. Tactics, especially the use of surprise, can make an en

Answer (score 112):

**Frodo didn't take 17 months**

He left Hobbiton on 22nd September 3018 and arrived in Mordor on 19th March 3019 - about 6 months.

**They travelled different distances**

Frodo travelled all the way from Hobbiton whereas Aragorn's army travelled from Minas Tirith, which was substantially closer.

By comparison, it takes Frodo from 5th March to 12th March to travel from the Black Gate to Shelob's Lair, which is only 7 days for a similar distance to that which Aragorn's army travelled.  Aragorn's army makes the journey from 18th March to 25th March - also 7 days.

**Frodo stopped plenty of times along the way**

In particular:

- Rivendell: 2 months.
- Lorien: 1 month.

Which reduces his journey time to 3 months.

In fact, if we look at the time from the Breaking of the Fellowship (26th February) to the destruction of the Ring (25th March) - before which Frodo and Aragorn were travelling together - we see that only 1 month passes.

So from that point onwards we can say that it actually took each **the same amount of time to travel to Mordor**, accepting that they went to different parts of Mordor, and with various delays and sidetracks along the way, from the time their routes diverged.

Source for all dates and times: *Tale of Years*, Return of the King.

Comment: He also had a few days with Tom Bombadil. Everyone seems to forget Tom :-(

Comment: @Po-ta-toe that's probably because Tom grants is zero relevance to the story :D

Comment: @VictimOfCircumstance - Were you not an active member of this SE before? I seem to recall someone with a very similar image profile providing many great answers based on Tolkien's work...

Comment: Also (as noted above), for most of the journey from the Falls to Mt. Doom, Frodo & Sam are trying very hard to stay concealed, which makes the journey.  Aragorn, OTOH, does most of his travel openly, and from Isengard onwards in company with military forces of various sizes.

Comment: Frodo also has shorter legs.

Comment: Also Aragorn and his army marched along purposefully, not stopping to check out plants or fall in pools.

Comment: "__marched along purposefully_". You could almost say he was a strider.

Comment: @Gusdor - true for the films, but absolutelly false for the books.

Answer (score 33):

Victim of Circumstance explains the basic duration.

As for "easily", Sauron could absolutely have fought them all the way along their route.  But why would he?  All his enemies are stupidly marching into a dead-end trap where they're ludicrously outnumbered and can easily be wiped out to the last man in one simple battle with nowhere to run to.  From Sauron's POV, Aragorn's strategy could only be absolute desperation, and there's no way he could possibly win.  The last thing Sauron would want to do is dissuade his enemies from making that mistake.

Comment: To add to this answer. This all was done to persuade Sauron that Aragorn is now wearing The Ring and tries to usurp Sauron.

Comment: @SokPomaranczowy wrong, it was to distract him from his own lands, where Frodo and Sam were.

Comment: @MarkGardner Actually it was for both reasons.

Comment: @MarkGardner - there is a specific passage in ROTK where Gandalf muses that Sauron might think Aragorn's attack the rash action of a new bearer of the One Ring before that new bearer learned to use it.  Remember that Aragorn had already goaded Sauron into a premature attack on Minas Tirith when he revealed himself as Isildur's heir to Sauron via the Palantir in TT.  Basically, the Dark Lord was already paranoid about Aragorn...

Comment: @MarkGardner The thought that Aragorn might be wearing the Ring is one mechanism by which this distraction was accomplished.

Comment: To be fair, the movies ignored the whole Sauron-might-think-Aragorn-has-the-One-Ring entirely, so it's an understandable confusion (even if someone read the book at some point, the movie's simplified narrative could easily smear over someone's older memories of the book's details in someone's mind).

Comment: @StoneTrue I'm not sure you can say Sauron's attack on Minas Tirith was "premature".  They took on the bulk of Gondor's army and beat them, then took on a rear attack from Rohan and beat them too.  Tolkein makes a proper mess of the reinforcements arriving on the Corsair ships - getting dozens of ships into a harbour and offloading tens of thousands of men in good order simply doesn't happen that quickly.  It's very much a deus-ex-machina, utterly impossible in reality.  The film is even worse for this with the Army of the Dead.

Comment: @Graham --- I can't find a figure for the number of ships, or the number of men on them, but it was certainly not tens of thousands. For comparison, the total size of Rohan's army was between 6,000 and 10,000 (The Muster of Rohan). You can get a good idea of the size of the armies in LotR from the last few pages of The Last Debate.

Comment: @IanThompson I don't think Tolkein gave a figure.  But we can work forwards to some extent (and I confess I'm relying on Wikipedia for numbers instead of going back to the book).  On one side there's 6000 Rohirrim, 3000 Gondorians and Gandalf.  On the other side were at least 30,000 orcs and men, plus war-elephants, trolls and the Nine.  Even allowing for the Rohirrim's charge, there still needed to be enough reinforcements to kill every last Mordorian and still have a strong army left.  Anything less than 10,000 would not be enough, and more realistically they'd need double that.

Comment: @Graham --- 6-10K is definitely right for the Rohirrim, but I haven't found the other figures in any canonical source. The complete Guide to Middle-Earth gives similar numbers, but I'm not sure of the basis for these. I don't have the book to hand, but I don't think Aragorn bringing 20K to Pelennor Fields, with more following later on foot, would fit with the numbers given in The Last Debate.

Comment: @Graham --- There is a question about the numbers of men at the Pelennor fields [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90752/4935). I've been through the books and posted an answer. The figure of 3,000 men of Gondor is far too small.